# 'docker network inspect host' has no ipaddresses

Tags: docker

We have an issue when we run our docker-compose up in host networking mode in that
the containers cannot see each other via their service names. The host is a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Docker 18.06 CE

Here is the output of  'docker network inspect host'. There are no ip addresses. We know our host is available as when we run without host networking all works fine. Anyone know why we are getting the output below?

```
 [
    {
      "Name": "host",
      "Id": 
      "63f64ed5074bde84b885cf91bb61c5050c88e1dfe4857f5caf18787eb6ba5329",
      "Created": "2018-07-10T12:01:22.1313782Z",
      "Scope": "local",
      "Driver": "host",
      "EnableIPv6": false,
      "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": []
      },
      "Internal": false,
      "Attachable": false,
      "Ingress": false,
      "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
      },
      "ConfigOnly": false,
      "Containers": {},
      "Options": {},
      "Labels": {}
   }
 ]
```

Comment: paste the docker run command

Answer (score 0):

The host network only configures the driver, everything else is the golang zero value. That's because there's nothing for docker to manage with the host network. The host network tells docker to not create or manage the networking namespace for any container attached. Instead, it leaves that container in the host namespace with any network interfaces that exist there.

If you want to see the network interfaces in your host, don't run a docker command. You can just run `ip a`.

Comment: Thanks, but why can't the containers see each other in host mode. I suppose what I am asking is how to get host mode working

Comment: @tech74 containers would see each other in host mode the same way two processes on the host running outside of docker would see each other. Would need to see a [mcve], but it sounds like you don't want host mode.